# Force GPU memory flush between OpenGL executions

Tags: opengl

If I do this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffer); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions1)+sizeof(vertexPositions2), vertexPositions1, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions1), sizeof(vertexPositions2), vertexPositions2); 
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

I get correct shapes displayed. Now, if I replace these lines by:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffer); 
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions1)+sizeof(vertexPositions2), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

I still get two correct shapes (while nothing has been added into the buffer). I suppose it is because the memory allocated for the buffer in both cases is the same. So in case 2, it actually uses vertices stored during case 1.

To check that, I just comment the line `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);`. The program crashes. Then I uncomment it and I get a black screen as expected.

So, is it really the memory initialized in case 1 that is actually used in case 2 (even if I did not initialized my buffer with any vertex)? Then, how could I avoid such side-effects to detect uninitilaized memore sooner?

**EDIT 1: using GL_STREAM_DRAW produces the same behavior**

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions1)+sizeof(vertexPositions2), vertexPositions1, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions1), sizeof(vertexPositions2), vertexPositions2);
```

**EDIT 2: "similar" use of uninitialized memory on CPU** (I am not asking why that or the differences between CPU and GPU. Just stating that random uninitialized memory would help too (if this is the actual problem here of course):

```
int a[2];
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}

a[0] = 1234; a[1] = 5678;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
}
```

2 executions in a row will produce:

```
-858993460
-858993460
1234
5678
```

Comment: Way to abuse the `GL_STATIC_DRAW` usage hint. If you are going to call `glBufferSubData (...)` immediately after calling `glBufferData (...)` call with that flag, you should pass NULL to the first call. Otherwise, use `GL_STREAM_DRAW`. They are just hints in the end, but you should use them the way they were intended.

Comment: The bigger question is why are you drawing using vertices that you have not given any data to? You have complete control over the indices that are drawn, you can easily restrict them to vertices that actually exist in your VBO.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: the main problem is that while coding, you do such errors. Having random memory helps track and find these errors. I am just trying to recreate an error and see how I could help track such errors in the future.

Comment: Well, do not expect any help from OpenGL. This is all implementation specific stuff. The behavior of using an uninitialized element buffer (or for that matter, one with elements that are out of range), for instance on NV hardware may be a bunch of garbage and on AMD simply no primitives drawn. That is the problem with OpenGL, each vendor implements the entire thing from scratch - and the OpenGL specification does not tell any of the vendors what they are supposed to do with uninitialized memory or even access to memory in a buffer object that is out of range (WebGL does this, though).

Comment: Ok, thanks. So is there any good practice while coding in debug mode to initialize all memory to 0 (at least)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a debugger tool might help you ( gDEBugger maybe ). Uninitialized memory is pretty much the same on the graphic card as it is on the main RAM. You could get the same kind of artifact reading random memory.

Comment: The problem here is that I feel the memory is less "random" and more persistent than normal RAM.

Comment: It really depends on the driver implementation. There is a lot of optimization going on when allocating memory on the graphic card that is not done on the main RAM.

Comment: If you read my edits, you can see what I mean by "more persistent" than with the CPU RAM.

Comment: Ok. It seems that using a debugger is the only alternative. Thanks.